# JQuery css Iphone not working

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    var winswidth = $(".span63").css("width");   
   if ($(".wrapper").width() < 350) {
      $(".wrapper .yazi").hide(0); 
    }else if ($(".wrapper").width() > 350) {
      $(".wrapper .yazi").show(0); 
    }
    var sayi=2;
    winswidth=parseInt(winswidth)-sayi;
     $(".wrapper .options-wrapper").css("width: " + winswidth);//not working
});
```

other phones is working. but the iPhone is not working.
Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(".wrapper .options-wrapper").css("width",  winswidth + "px");
```

Comment: var winswidth = $(".span63").css("width");  fetches the value along with px don't you think.

Comment: @Riddler he used parseInt, if it is success then it wont have 'px' in the value

Comment: @ABeratAdıgüzel - But It is also one issue in your code Anoop noticed.